# nested boolean operators in Solr queries

Tags: solr

I'm having trouble getting Solr queries with nested boolean operators to work as expected.  For example, I'd like to select documents where a field is missing or contains 1.  I thought I could write:

```
(!field:*) OR field:1
```

But this query returns 0 documents.  `!field:*` alone returns 282 documents and `field:1` returns 34.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
(-field:[* TO *] AND *:*) OR field:1
```